# I want to add purchase code activation in my Shopify theme how can I do?

Tags: javascript, shopify, themes, liquid

I want to add the purchase verification activation in Shopify theme after that I will upload my Shopify theme to the themeforest

I expectimg that you will help me to create.So I can sell my Shopify theme and buyer use code to purchase Shopify theme.I want to secure by using envato purchase verification system.